# Convert Java public DSA or RSA key to a format which Node understands

Tags: java, javascript, android, node.js, cryptography

I want to sign messages in Android and verify the signature in a Node.js web app.

On the android side, I create the key as follows:

```
 KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
 generator.initialize(dsabits, sr);
 KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
 PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();


 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
 fos.write(publicKey.getEncoded());
 fos.close();
```

Now I would like to use that public key to validate messages in Node.js:

```
var messageBase64 = "SGVsbG8gRmVsaXgh";
var signatureBase64 = 'MCwCFF9mV7/m3D8qjJKZSj3JMtqEmCQmAhQk9wSVnyOQgvUd5/n/iGAr4cNxLw=='
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');

var verify = crypto.createVerify('dsaWithSHA');
var buffer = new Buffer(messageBase64, 'base64');
verify.update(buffer);
var key = fs.readFileSync('./keys/public.key');

var isValid = verify.verify(key, signatureBase64 , 'base64');
```

How do I convert the Java generated key file to one which Node can read? Or how do can I create a key pair which I could use in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
    PEMWriter writer = new PEMWriter(new FileWriter("test.pem"));
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(3072);
    KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    writer.writeObject(keyPair.getPublic());
    writer.close();
```

I've used `RSA` instead of `DSA` (DSA keys should work as well though). DSA should only be used for legacy applications. On Java SE it is even restricted to 512 or 1024 bits keys, which is not considered secure anymore. If your Android API misbehaves, try `[SpongyCastle](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/)`.